# Why is the iterator print hashcode not the actual value?

Tags: java, iterator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);

    Iterator<int[]> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: yes @ernest_k it is compiling .

Comment: Note that when printing `it.next()` you get the result of the `toString()`method of the object pointed by the iterator, not the hashcode of the iterator itself as stated in the title.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `List<Integer>`, not a `List<int[]>`:

```
//easier and more common way to build a List<Integer>
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

Iterator<Integer> it2 = list1.iterator();
while (it2.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare your array as `Integer[]` and use the same code:

```
Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);

Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a list who's elements are arrays of type int.

```
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Now when you are using an iterator:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next()); // it.next() returns an int[]
}
```

so `it.next()` gives us an array of type `int[]` and `toString()` is called on it,  which just returns array hashcode. 
However if you add

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(it.next()));
```

you see the context of the array.  But that is not what you probably want  and all you need to do is just to change your `iterator` and `list` types to `<Integer>` instead of `int[]` as explained in ernest_k answer.